# Иконки в comboBox в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, icon, combobox

Как сделать в comboBox'е (выпадающем списке) вместо строк текста иконки? Что бы их как и текст можно было выбирать

Comment: Смотрите [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10670/Image-ComboBox-Control).

Answer (score 1):

Для подобных целей есть компонент ImageList.

Comment: Его можно реализовать как выпадающий список?